# Command substitution in bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to use a variable inside of a `$()` but it's not working.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Please enter the username (without domain and in lowercase)"
read $username
echo "$username"
userid="$(id -u $username)"
echo "$userid"
```

The result of `echo $userid` is `0`. Shouldn't it give me the userid of the user?

Comment: Pretty much every line of that code has problems. Use shellcheck.net to find them.

Comment: Cargo-cult programming spotted =)

Comment: So I have cleaned up my code and I am getting a result... just the wrong result, please see edited post. Apologies for the noob code, I am teaching myself bash by just writing it, trying to read up as much as I can.

Comment: Found the problem! should have been read username, not read $username.  Thanks for getting me on the right track. cheers

Comment: Done. Thanks Gilles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
read username
userid="$(id -u "$username")"
echo "$userid"
```

#### Notes :

- as stated by @chepner, when you have shell code, before asking, pass it to shellcheck.net
- no space allowed at variable declaration
- no `$` in left part variable assignation
- place quotes at the right place:

"Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words